# sendkey enter to a pop up on application in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to close this startup pop up in program by sending an enter key programmatically. I have followed some of the examples in this site about creating a class within the same namespace to handel this, but I don't know how to use it in main form. check the code below from the sendkey class. thank you in advance

```
class winhandler
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint procId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
    public const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    public const uint EM_SETSEL = 0x000000B1;
    public const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    public const uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
    public const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

    string title = "Card ....";
    public void cancelwindows()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, title);

        uint loginWindowProcId;
        uint loginWindowThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out loginWindowProcId);

        // now I can just use .NET to find the Process for me...
        Process loginWindowProcess = null;

        if (0 != loginWindowProcId)
        {
            loginWindowProcess = Process.GetProcessById((int)loginWindowProcId);
            loginWindowProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to use it, just do public static void cancelwindows() and then call it from your main method using winhandler.cancelwindows(). If you make everything static, you can call it without instantiating it... alternatively, you could move that method into your own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with a lot of password protected excel sheets and I wrote something similar to type the password for me whenever it is requested.

Here is an example of a form that waits for a window containing "Notepad" to open before typing into it and closing.

This example uses a timer to check for the window every 500 milliseconds. Obviously, if you're expecting the window to appear, you could simply use a while loop until it appears or something similar.

I'm not 100% sure which part it is that you're having trouble with, but please feel free to let me know if this doesn't answer your question :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CloseWindowTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer windowTimer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            windowTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            windowTimer.Interval = 500;
            windowTimer.Tick += t_Tick;
            windowTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetActiveWindowTitle().Contains("Notepad"))
            {
                try
                {
                    windowTimer.Enabled = false;
                    SendKeys.SendWait("Notepad Detected");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                catch (Exception wtf) { MessageBox.Show(wtf.ToString()); }
            }
        }

        private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```