# Click on Excel message box from C#

Tags: c#, vba

I have an automation project written in C# that drives Excel. Part of what I need to do in this automation project is click on checkboxes. Each checkbox has a sub attached to it that will raise a message box that asks for the action to be confirmed with a `vbYesNo` message box.

I C#, when I set the value of the checkbox to `true`, the `vbYesNo` message box pops up and I have to manually click the `YES` button for my test execution to proceed.

Is there a way I can have my automation project "click" on the `YES` button for me?

Comment: Call a macro that sets a flag that suppresses the msgbox calls in the VBA.

Comment: If you don't want to handle it through excel, you can just have it press the button automatically for you by using this code from a previous answer. Just have it press the "Y" key (or tab/enter) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723919/sendkey-enter-to-a-pop-up-on-application-in-c-sharp/26724598#26724598

Comment: If you don't want to look for the popup by handle/text, you can just wait a certain amount of time and use SendKeys.SendWait("Y"); - safer to wait for the window, but one line of code this way.

Comment: Nice and easy solutions! Where do I put `SendKeys.SendWait("Y");`? In my project, it looks like C# is in the middle of executing one line of code when the pop-up appears. It doesn't look like that one line is finished executing until the yes button is clicked, which would make the `SendKeys` line useless. Is there a way that I can send a key after 2 seconds or something?